# Do I have to convert my PHP app into MVC in order to use Zend_search_lucene?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I have finished writing my own web application now. It is written in PHP with MYSQL DB and I did not use any MVC framework at all. Now I want to add a local search functionality for my app and from looking at the other posts here, Zend_Search_Lucene seems to be a good option for me.

Now if I want to use Zend_Search_Lucene do I have to install the whole Zend framework then re-write my app and adapt them into its MVC framework ?

I am looking to use just the search feature of the framework, and right now I probably do not really mind installing the whole framework, but I surely do if I have to make large-scale changes to my app..

appreciate any answer-suggestion, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the Zend_Search_Lucene package, you don't need to use the whole framework and/or MVC aspect of it. If you don't want to install the whole framework, you have to check package dependencies that Zend_Search_Lucene has. There are some automatic ways of doing this, here are some:

- [ZF dependency manager](http://www.binpress.com/app/zf-dependency-manager/30)
- [Zend Framework Automatic Dependency Tracking](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/01/zend-framework-automatic-dependency-tracking/)

If you google it you'll sure find more.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the question: no, you won't have to change it, you may use Zend Framework libraries independently.

I won't give you any tutorials on Lucene, though.